# React Native bundle integrity with OTA

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, code-push, react-native-code-push

When one OTA the js bundle inside a react native app (via CodePush or similar), how does one ensure the bundle is intact?

with App Store or Google Play, the app / apk file is signed, thus ensuring the owner approved it, and also no one touched the file after. But seems like react native js bundle OTA does NOT have such protection, is that true?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1093